# Is it possible to decompose Scala match statements using partial functions?

Tags: scala, switch-statement, pattern-matching, decomposition, partialfunction

I have a match statement like this:

```
    i match {
      case x if x == 0 ⇒
        romanNumeral

      case x if x >= 1000 ⇒
        this.roman(i - 1000, s"${romanNumeral}M")

      case x if x >= 900 ⇒
        this.roman(i - 900, s"${romanNumeral}CM")

      // etc.
```

Depending on how this is formatted, it could be about 30 lines of redundant code.
So I'm wondering whether it is possible to make this code more dry.

So I created a partial function:

```
  private def toRoman(upperGuard: Int, token: String, romanNumeral: String): String = {
    case value: Int if value >= upperGuard ⇒
      this.roman(upperGuard - 1, s"$romanNumeral$token")
  }
```

which I then tried to include into the above matcher like:

```
    i match {
      case x if x == 0 ⇒
        romanNumeral

        toRoman(1000, "M", romanNumeral)
        toRoman(900, "CM", romanNumeral)
        // etc.
```

... But this won't work because Scala's compiler doesn't recognize these functions are the case statements it is looking for.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Please don't leave repetitive comments, as they are not helpful. If you post what may be perceived as low quality code, which you have done, you can expect answers which will comment on this. You would be better off reading answers more thoroughly before quickly downvoting and copy and pasting comments. Happy coding.

Comment: @Snickers3192, I read your "answer".  It didn't provide me with any useful information except to disagree with the premise of the question, which is decidedly not useful.  Compare with Krzysztof's answer where he saw what I intended to do and told me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your cases as partial functions:

```
private def toRoman(upperGuard: Int, token: String, romanNumeral: String): PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case value if value >= upperGuard =>
      this.roman(upperGuard - 1, s"$romanNumeral$token")
}

val firstCase: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case x if x == 0 => romanNumeral
}
```

And then compose it like this:

```
val toRomanPartialFunction = firstCase
  .orElse(toRoman(1000, "M", romanNumeral))
  .orElse(toRoman(900, "CM", romanNumeral))
```

After that you could use it like regular function:

```
toRomanPartialFunction.apply(443) 
toRomanPartialFunction(443)
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!   But why that last line "apply(443)"?  Do I need it?  What does the contained value mean in general? Or here specifically?

Comment: @BrianKessler PartialFunction works as a regular function, so you can call with with `apply()` or just `()`. I updated my answer, maybe this time it's more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to make the code less repetitive, first things first:

- Scala´s compiler doesn't recognise these functions as case statements because they are functions;
- Second thing, that function is not actually a partial function;
- Finally, those matches are ok to be like that, if you find a way of reducing lines of code by grouping in some kind of function like you did great but I don't find them redundant, unless you can redo it with a function like I said.

Ps: That function don't do the some thing as the case

Comment: Please see @Krzysztof Atłasik's answer.  I haven't accepted yet (subject to testing), but he seems to understand what I am trying to do and focused on the intention instead of the implementation (I didn't really care about the word "match").

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a pattern matching expression, you are just writing an `if else` statement. If you want to return a function, you would write: `x => this.something(x,"foo-bar")` You have no need for `case x`. If you are only having one expression on the LHS `case x` you have no need for pattern matching, and can just use `if else`. Pattern matching without a class hierarchy doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please see @Krzysztof Atłasik's answer.  I haven't accepted yet (subject to testing), but he seems to understand what I am trying to do and focused on the intention instead of the implementation (I didn't really care about the word "match").

Comment: Please see my answer.